# Gmail Add-on: Something went wrong when executing the add-on

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

The Smartsheet for Gmail Add-on works for all Gmail accounts but not for one specific one. The add-on uses OAuth and it appears that all the interactions with our servers are successful. No errors are logged in our servers. With two different Gmail accounts and the same OAuth user, one succeeds and the other fails. I get a generic error that says "Something went wrong when executing the add-on". What could cause that?

Comment: Did you by any chance find what was causing it? We recently started getting this with a handful of users and can’t see any logs that can help determining the cause.